# How do I Copy and paste columns into a different workbook starting at a different row? Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, intersect

This is my VBA code so far:

```
Sub refreshActionLog()
'Dim current As Worksheet
'Dim source As Workbook
'Dim sourcesheet As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set current = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log")
Set source = Workbooks("G:\Data\Shared\Action Logs\merged.xlsx").Worksheets("merged")

With Intersect(source.Sheets("merged").Columns("A:I"), source.UsedRange)
     .Columns("A").Copy Destination:=current.Range("A6")
     .Columns("B").Copy Destination:=current.Range("B6")
     .Columns("C").Copy Destination:=current.Range("C6")
     .Columns("D").Copy Destination:=current.Range("D6")
     .Columns("E").Copy Destination:=current.Range("E6")
     .Columns("G").Copy Destination:=current.Range("F6")
     .Columns("H").Copy Destination:=current.Range("G6")
     .Columns("H").Copy Destination:=current.Range("H6")
     .Columns("I").Copy Destination:=current.Range("I6")
End With
End Sub
```

I get the error "Run time error '9': Subscript out of range" at the line:

```
Set source = Workbooks("G:\Data\Shared\Action 
Logs\merged.xlsx").Worksheets("merged")
```

Furthermore, is the 'Intersect' the best way to copy and paste columns starting at a particular row. I wouldn't know as my code will not go any further due to the run time error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you do any copy, open your `merged.xlsx`:

```
Set source = Workbooks.Open("G:\Data\Shared\Action Logs\merged.xlsx")
```

Now set the sheet:

```
Dim sourceSheet as Worksheet: Set sourceSheet = source.Worksheets("merged")
```

Now you can do the copy

```
sourceSheet.Range("A:I").Copy current.Range("A6")
```

I haven't tested this code so there might be some syntax errors but that's the general gist

> Note: Don't forget to close 'source' workbook